# Calling a function in separate file

Tags: c

I am trying to call a function that's located in another c file, however, the function is of a datatype that was created in a linked list and the typedef is called "treat." My code is below:

```
typedef struct micro{
    int id;                 
    char user[51];          
    char text[141];         

    struct micro *next;  
}treat;

treat * createMicro(treat * treatList);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int menu_op;

  if(argc <= 1) {
    printf("Please enter a number argument between 1 and 8.");
    exit(0);
  }
  else if(argc > 2) {
    printf("Too many arguments.");
    exit(0);
  }

  menu_op = atoi(argv[1]);

  if(menu_op == 1) {
    createMicro(treat *treatList); //Where the error is coming from
  }

}
```

My second function is within a file called, "createMicro.c", how do I call the function within this file, from my main.c function? When I compile, I am faced with the following error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:31:17: error: expected expression before ‘treat’
     createMicro(treat *treatList);
```

Comment: Well, why are you calling `printf` like `printf("Too many arguments.");` and not `printf((const char *)"Too many arguments.");`? Similarly for `exit(0)`: why not `exit(int 0)`? Why not `atoi(char *argv[1])`?

Comment: `if (menu_op == 1) { treat treatList = {0}; createMicro(&treatList); }` ... but, of course, the variable definition should have enough scope for your requirements (scope just inside the `if` is too narrow).

Comment: Look at how you're calling `printf`, `exit`, and `atoi`, then look at how you're calling `createMicro`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: You didn't include the header. You should write a header file `createMicro.h` with both the struct and the fuction definitions and include it in the file with your `main()` function with `#include "createMicro.h"`

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "Too many arguments."); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error I needed to fix was the parameter. Instead of:

```
createMicro(treat *treatList);
```

It should be:

```
createMicro(treatList);
```

And have the variable 'treatList' declared and initialized to zero before calling "creatMicro"

Comment: since `treatList` is a pointer to a linked list, declare it like: `treat *treatList = NULL;`  then do NOT include the variable type in the call parameters for the actual call statement

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are already calling that function, the error is clearly about the syntax error in the parameter list. You wrote a declaration instead of giving a parameter, most probably you just copied the prototype of the function.

Change this:

```c
    createMicro(treat *treatList);
```

… into this, if your function allows `NULL`:

```c
    createMicro(NULL);
```

… or this, if you like to provide a pre-filled `treat`:

```c
    treat myTreatList = {
        23, /* id */
        "me user", /* user */
        "some text", /* text */
        NULL /* next */
    };
    createMicro(&myTreatList);
```

BTW, you will need to store the result of the call somewhere…

Answer (score -1):

Rename the file extension from ".c" to ".h" and include it:

```
#include "createMicro.h"
```

Comment: Please remove that suggestion. Include files should only contain declarations and never definitions (code). Not observing that is an anti pattern and a recipe for violations of the One Definition Rule.

Comment: @SergeBallesta C doesn't have templates.

Comment: @SerceBallesta Declarations are also code.

Comment: I know it. But I tried to use *common language*. Anyway, putting a **definition** in a file and including it is an anti pattern.

Comment: @SergeBallestra While C and C++ may appear to be closely related, they should be considered completely different, even though they have some "common" parts.